# How to resolve element still not visible after 30000ms error in perfecto using WebdriverIo

Tags: javascript, perfecto

I am trying to click on an element in perfecto however I get element not Visible after 30000ms error using:
browser.waitForVisible('element locator');
browser.waitForVisible('click');

the element locator is unique and correct when checked in DOM.

If I try to use browser.keys('down arrow');
It does nothing

Using browser.scroll('element locator'); or browser.moveToObject('element locator');
gives error:
com.perfectomobile.selenium.server.PerfectoMobileDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasTouchScreen

Though scroll and moveToObject has worked on other screens.

Can anyone please help on what other options can be used to click on perfecto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `browser.execute("arguments[0].click();", element);`

where element is your object that you want to click.